# Please make sure that the file is an Office Add-in manifest

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I am trying to publish an Excel add-in, here is `manifest.xml` that I am submitting to [sellerdashboard](https://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com/Application/Overview/Create?type=800001).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>ab2991e7-fe64-465b-a2f1-c865247ef434</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="AppName" />
  <Description DefaultValue="AppName"/>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.example.com/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

However, I got an message `Please make sure that the file is an Office Add-in manifest`. As a consequence, when I click on `NEXT` in the bottom of the page, it says `Please enter an app version.`, which should be auto-populated from the xml file.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have  a space or a blank line before  the initial `<?xml`. Make sure the very first character is `<`.

The other issue is this is using the v1.0 manifest. The Store requires v1.1. The v1.1 manifest is documented [here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests).

After 7/1/16 Store submissions will also be required to support [Add-in Commands](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) for Word, PowerPoint and Excel (Outlook is already required).

Comment: before the initial?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some other potential issues.

Comment: Thank you... The key is to use the v1.0 manifest. So far I don't see it is mandatory to have add-in commands...

Comment: Another question: `Privacy Document Link` is mandatory, do you know where I could find a sample?

Comment: I don't know of any good samples but their are not many hard and fast requirements in regards to it's content. So long as you link to a published privacy policy that covers how and when you use or resell data it should be sufficient.